# Override Bootstrap CSS with custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small problem overriding some of Bootstrap's CSS style.

The standard definition of a bootstrap table has the following code:

```
.table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I would like to set margin-bottom to 0px, using my own css code, but I'm having some problems overriding it.

This is my code:

```
table .table.table-responsive .table-middle {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: your code will only change the object with the class 'table-middle' inside an object with class 'table' and 'table-responsive' which is inside a table.

Comment: <table class="table table-responsive table-middle">

Not quite sure what you're refering to. I've applied the class to my table.

Comment: post your html and css so i can see the layout thanks.

Comment: table .table-responsive .table-middle try check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add important. That is a bad habit to fall into and will cause you even more headaches in the future. Plus, I doubt it will solve the problem. Instead, try to find out why your targeting (table .table.table-responsive .table-middle) isn't targeting and overriding the table you want.

The easiest way to do this is via Chrome or Firefox's "Inspect Element". Take a look at the table you want to change. See where the margin-bottom lies. Maybe it's on `.table.blue` or `.container .table` or something.

However, judging by your targeting, I doubt that is an issue. Instead, I believe you aren't targeting the element you want.

```
 table .table.table-responsive .table-middle
```

will look for all `<table>` elements, then look for children of that `<table>` element with the classname of `table` AND `table-responsive`, and then look inside that element for children with the classname of `table-middle`.

Your HTML would have to look like this:

```
<table>
    <??? class='table table-responsive>
        <??? class="table-middle">
```

Instead, I'm guessing you have a `<table>` element that looks something like this:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-middle">
```

Simply writing `table.table` or `table.table-responsive`should override bootstrap. Worst comes to worst, `.table.table-responsive.table-middle` will almost certainly work.

Remember

```
.classname .another-classname
```

with a space goes parent -> child

```
.classname.another-classname
```

without a space is one element that has both of those classes.

Comment: i believe  table  .table-responsive .table-middle might work.

Answer (score -2):

try adding the `important`.

```
table .table.table-responsive .table-middle {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it would. But I don't think this is a good practice, though.

Answer (score -2):

Try Using !important after the css text. I have shown a example below 
padding-bottom: 4.5rem !important;

Comment: Where is the example below?