# How to override a bootstrap class which already has !important in its class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to override a bootstrap `shadow-sm` class with my own shadow class. Here is the bootstrap class.

**for some reason I don't want to change class name**

```
.shadow-sm {
box-shadow: 0 .125rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,.075)!important;
}
```

I tried to override with my custom style

```
.shadow-sm {
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12)!important;
}
```

but only bootstrap style applies

Now how do I override?

```css
.shadow-sm {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12)!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 p-1">
      <a class="btn fb btn-block shadow-sm rounded-pill" href="#" role="button"><strong>Facebook</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my custom style with class that bootstrap already has

### tried below question but nothing works

[How can I override Bootstrap CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles)

[How can I override bootstrap classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243076/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-classes)

[How to override bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179997/how-to-override-bootstrap)

[Override Bootstrap CSS with custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031596/override-bootstrap-css-with-custom-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the link to your css file *after* the bootstrap css file. No need to use `!important` doing it that way.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 p-1">
      <a class="btn fb btn-block shadow-sm rounded-pill" href="#" role="button"><strong>Facebook</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this works. i named second file as `main-style.css` when i rename it to style it works now. **does the file name has to be style.css** also can you mention why the file name should be `style.css`

Comment: More than likely the file was locally cached and by renaming it you got a fresh copy.

Comment: Maybe you need press `shift+f5` to reload with cache cleared after change some css

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or id to your element and assign your attributes there, example

if class .imp has !important attribute

```
<div class="main">
<div class="imp newclass">
</div>
</div>
```

You will have to access the element like;

```
.main .newclass{}
```

OR

```
div.newclass{
}
```

Comment: i was asking about override method

Answer (score 0):

That;s related to CSS Specificity (basically order of precedence). You can know more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

**In Your Case:**

You can super-override CSS properties, by adding additional class of your choice.

Let's add `shadow-custom` class along with `shadow-sm` class.

Then using both to override default behaviour:

```css
.shadow-sm.shadow-custom{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12)!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 p-1">
      <a class="btn fb btn-block shadow-sm shadow-custom rounded-pill" href="#" role="button"><strong>Facebook</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i tried this method and it works but i can't add all classes with `shadow-custom` and i asked override method